# D3.js radial collapsible radial tree (1 branch per ramification)

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, tree, geometry

I am making a radial version of the [collapsible tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) by Mike Bostock.

I would like to have a single branch per group of ramification instead of a branch per element.

Here is what I have so far: 
[image]

The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLt39mk4/) for my current representation is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cLt39mk4/).

The extra commented lines in the `var flare`are just extra lines meant for density testing, to see how it looks with a lot of info, as it is intended.

The white circle is used to hide the root element and the links to the first level on a white background. To remove it, simply delete the following lines:

```
var circle = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("cy", 0)
    .attr("r", radius - 5)
    .style("fill", "white");
```

Below is what I want to have: 
[image]

How it works from root to level 1 does not matter, as long as the level 1 elements form a circle (here with 3 level 1 elements), as I will still be hiding level 0 (root) to level 1

However, it is important that the spacing of the parent element changes according to the children being collapsed or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take on your illustration.  Essentially, it's a very custom path generator.  I've attempted to comment it well, so let me know if you have any questions.

```
link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {

      // depth zero, don't draw, this is your "hidden" links
      if (d.source.depth === 0) return "";

      // if we have children
      if (d.source.children) {

        // sum the angles to find the midpoint of the children
        var pad = 20, //<-- pad is the step off distance to children
           sum = 0;
        d.source.children.forEach(function(c) {
          sum += c.x;
        });

        // this is the mid point position
        var ma = ((sum / d.source.children.length) - 90) * (Math.PI / 180),
          mr = d.source.children[0].y - pad,
          mid = [mr * Math.cos(ma), mr * Math.sin(ma)]; //x,y position

        // this is the source position
        var sa = (d.source.x - 90) * (Math.PI / 180),
          sr = d.source.y - pad,
          source = [sr * Math.cos(sa), sr * Math.sin(sa)];

        // this is the final target position
        var ta = (d.target.x - 90) * (Math.PI / 180),
          tr = d.target.y - pad,
          target = [tr * Math.cos(ta), tr * Math.sin(ta)];

        // this is the arc from mid to target
        var dx = target[0] - source[0],
          dy = target[1] - source[1],
          dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        // this is the line from the source, to the mid and arced to children
        return "M" + source +
          "L" + mid +
          "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0," + (ma < ta ? 1 : 0) + " " + target[0] + "," + target[1];
      }
    });
```

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cLt39mk4/1/).

**UPDATES TO COMMENTS**

Check this version out.  It drops the custom arc I wrote and instead uses a [d3.svg.arc](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#_arc) generator.  It also limits the drawing to just the first and last child to remove redundant paths.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .node {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    
    .node text {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    
    #svg {
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <div id="svg"></div>
  <script>
    flare = {
      "name": "root",
      "children": [{
          "name": "item1",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item2"
          }, {
            "name": "item3"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        },

        {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "item4",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item5"
          }, {
            "name": "item6"
          }, {
            "name": "item7"
          }]
        },

        {
          "name": "item8",
          "children": [{
            "name": "item9"
          }, {
            "name": "item10"
          }]
        }
      ]
    };

    //variables used to modify some basic properties of the svg elements
    var divHeight = document.getElementById('svg').offsetHeight;
    var divWidth = document.getElementById('svg').clientWidth;
    var radius = 75;
    var separation = 2;

    var diameter = 800;

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 120,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 120
      },
      width = diameter,
      height = diameter;

    var i = 0,
      duration = 350,
      root;

    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
      .size([360, diameter / 2 - 80])
      .separation(function(a, b) {
        return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : separation) / a.depth;
      });
    //last line is the separation between branches of the tree when clicked

    var diagonal = d3.svg.line.radial();
    //    .projection(function(d) { var r = d.y, a = (d.x - 90) / 180 * Math.PI;
    //  return [r * Math.cos(a), r * Math.sin(a)]; });

    var svg = d3.select("#svg").append("svg")
      //.attr("width", width)
      //.attr("height", height)
      .attr("width", divWidth)
      .attr("height", divHeight)
      .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
        svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + "," + d3.event.translate[1] + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
      })).on("dblclick.zoom", null)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + divWidth / 2 + "," + divHeight / 2 + ")")
      .append("g");

    //alert("W = " + divWidth + ", H = " + divHeight);

    root = flare;
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

    root.children.forEach(collapse); // start with all children collapsed
    update(root);

    //create a circle in the center to remove root and first level of links
    var circle = svg.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 0)
      .attr("cy", 0)
      .attr("r", radius - 5)
      .style("fill", "white");

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

    function update(source) {

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * radius;
      });

      // Update the nodes…
      var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
          return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

      // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
        .on("click", click);

      nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

      nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        //.attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + (d.name.length * 8.5)  + ")"; })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // Transition nodes to their new position.
      var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
        })

      nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

      nodeUpdate.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + (d.name.length + 50) + ")";
        });

      // TODO: appropriate transform
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "diagonal(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
        .remove();

      nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6);

      nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // Update the links…
      var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d) {
          return d.target.id;
        });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
          };
          return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
          });
        });

      // Transition links to their new position.
      var arc = d3.svg.arc();

      link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {

          if (d.source.depth === 0) return "";
          
          if (d.source.children) {
            
            if (d.source.children[0] !== d.target &&
                d.source.children[d.source.children.length - 1] !== d.target)
              return ""
            
            var pad = 10,
              sum = 0;
            d.source.children.forEach(function(c) {
              sum += c.x;
            });

            // this is the mid point position
            var ma1 = ((sum / d.source.children.length) - 90) * (Math.PI / 180),
              ma2 = ((sum / d.source.children.length)) * (Math.PI / 180),
              mr = d.source.children[0].y - pad,
              mid = [mr * Math.cos(ma1), mr * Math.sin(ma1)];

            // this is the source position
            var sa = (d.source.x - 90) * (Math.PI / 180),
              sr = d.source.y - pad,
              source = [sr * Math.cos(sa), sr * Math.sin(sa)];

            // this is the final target position
            var ta = (d.target.x) * (Math.PI / 180),
              tr = d.target.y - pad,
              target = [tr * Math.cos(ta), tr * Math.sin(ta)];

            // this is the arc from mid to target
            var dx = target[0] - source[0],
              dy = target[1] - source[1],
              dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
              
            arc.innerRadius(tr-1)
              .outerRadius(tr)
              .startAngle(ma2)
              .endAngle(ta);
              
            console.log(arc())
            
            return "M" + source + "L" + mid + arc();

           /* return "M" + source +
              "L" + mid +
              "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0," + (ma < ta ? 1 : 0) + " " + target[0] + "," + target[1];
           */
          }
        });

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
          };
          return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
          });
        })
        .remove();

      // Stash the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });
    }

    // Toggle children on click.
    function click(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }

      update(d);
    }

    // Collapse nodes
    function collapse(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Plunker version [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lp0Td1CMURgkAYwkmXdc?p=preview).

Comment: That is a very good start! However, the arcs all have their own path, and when you use a lot of data, they do not look like they are on the same arc at all (http://i.imgur.com/GxnmWsZ.png). What would probably solve this would be not drawing an arc custom from the end of the line to the child, but always draw the same outer circle connecting to each children, so that only the size changes, not the radius or the center. I will try to build on that, but feel free to update it, and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Maybe making the mid point position further (finding the right place to put it) would solve the problem? My math is really bad so I am currently trying to figure out how to move the midpoint, and so the beginning of the arc.

Comment: @MorganFR, check updates above.  Fixes the issues you raise.  And it's  a better implementation.

Comment: That is exactly what i'm looking for! The last thing I need is to reduce the angle of the children starting at level 2. it is set on this line `var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([360, diameter / 2 - 80])`, but if i change it, it also changes the max angle of the first level. That will probably be a new question later.

Comment: How do I have to change `var sa = (d.source.x - 90) * (Math.PI / 180), sr = d.source.y - pad, source = [sr * Math.cos(sa), sr * Math.sin(sa)];` to start the branch at the end of the text rather than the beginning?

Comment: @MorganFR, calculate `sr` as `sr = d.source.y - (pad * -5),`